# toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener not working

Tags: android, toolbar, drawerlayout

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener this function is not working have no clue why.

activity_main.xml Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".login.LoginActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

container_main.xml Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Java Activity class

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;


    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();
        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }
        };
        mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("COMECOU", "COMECOU");
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }


    }

    /**
     * Displaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new CommunityFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new PagesFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

}
```

I forgot to say that if I slide I can see the menu is just the buttons is not logging neither being triggered.

UPDATE

Please see my answer if you want to know how to solve it.

Comment: @jlam55555 no just the listener is not triggered

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Another thing to remember is that

**calling**

`toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()`

**before**

`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

**won't work.**

Comment: @Mohammad Mahtabi Why shouldn't it work? Can't find any clue.

Answer (score 8):

I see that you are using the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and hence `setNavigationOnClickListener()` is the wrong one. The right one is `setToolbarNavigationClickListener()`. This will make it behave like a toggle button.

```
mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("TOU AQUI", "TOU AQUI");
    }
});
```

Comment: I've updated my code I did what you said but nothing happens :(

Comment: try `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)`.

Comment: I finally found the mistake is layout related I posted my own answer.

Comment: In that case, could you edit you question so the correct layout is posted.

Comment: I just place the answer I will update the question pointing to my answer.

Comment: Where is the answer @PedroAGSantos ?

Comment: My Answer is down @MarcoZanetti sorry I deleted it because I believe there is better answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `ActionBarDrawerToggle#setToolbarNavigationClickListener` in your case.

From the [Android Documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setToolbarNavigationClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))

> When DrawerToggle is constructed with a Toolbar, it sets the click listener on the Navigation icon. If you want to listen for clicks on the Navigation icon when DrawerToggle is disabled (setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean), you should call this method with your listener and DrawerToggle will forward click events to that listener when drawer indicator is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake we can't place toolbar outside of the DrawerLayout

here is how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#2196F3"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case - ScrollView has handled all touches. I have added `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` after Toolbar and it has worked. Hope I helped someone )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/common_toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        >

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    ... ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is in `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. That's how constructor looks like:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, Toolbar toolbar, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, DrawerArrowDrawable slider, @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes, @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
        //...
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mDrawerIndicatorEnabled) {
                    toggle();
                } else if (mToolbarNavigationClickListener != null) {
                    mToolbarNavigationClickListener.onClick(v);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

And I can't really understand the logic:

1. `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener` sets click listener for hamburger icon
2. when user click on hamburger:

   2.1 if hamburger visible then open/hide drawer

   2.2 if hamburger is not visible then call click listener.

So for most cases hamburger icon should be visible, hence in all these cases `setNavigationOnClickListener` doesn't work and useless.

Probably it should look like this:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, Toolbar toolbar, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, DrawerArrowDrawable slider, @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes, @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                toggle();
                if (mToolbarNavigationClickListener != null) {
                    mToolbarNavigationClickListener.onClick(v);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

A workaround solution could be overriding `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener` and calling `toggle` there. Though the method is package private:

```
package android.support.v7.app

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.View


object SupportUtils {
    fun setHamburgerListener(listener: () -> Unit,
                             drawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle,
                             drawerLayout: DrawerLayout,
                             toolbar: Toolbar) {
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(object : DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {
            override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) {
                drawerToggle.onDrawerStateChanged(newState)
            }

            override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                drawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset)
            }

            override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
                drawerToggle.onDrawerClosed(drawerView)
            }

            override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
                drawerToggle.onDrawerOpened(drawerView)
            }

        })

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            listener()
            drawerToggle.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private fun setUpToolbarWithHomeAsUp() {

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val actionBar = supportActionBar


        actionBar?.let{
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                //What ever you want
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```