# toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener not working with AppBarLayout

Tags: android

Back button is not clickable. Tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320203/toolbar-setnavigationonclicklistener-not-working) but it doesn't work.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_navbar_cancel)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { Log.d("Test", "Clicked!") }
}
```

**title_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    style="?attr/appBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@id/toolbar"
        style="?attr/toolBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="?attr/toolBarTitleStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/intro_bold_caps"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow_pre_lollipop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow_pre_lollipop" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**ic_navbar_cancel.xml**

```
<path
    android:fillColor="#003b5a"
    android:pathData="M18,18 L30,30 M18,30 L30,18"
    android:strokeColor="#003b5a"
    android:strokeWidth="3"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using the `setSupportActionBar()` method use the `ActionBar` API:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        Log.d("Test", "Clicked!")
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```